# Why is orthogonality a requirement after $R^2$ for linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Geometrically it makes sense, as in $R^3$ coplanarity cannot be avoided unless you add a new direction but why is $R^2$ an exception?

Comment: Can't quite interpret what you mean by "after" here. Do you mean "for"? Orthogonality *isn't* a requirement for linear independence.

Comment: It's not: The vectors $(0, 1)$ and $(1, 1)$ are independent and not orthogonal.

Comment: Maybe you are getting it backwards. It *is* true that if you have a set of pairwise orthogonal nonzero vectors, then they are linearly independent.

Comment: I thought for $n \geq 3, R^n$ pairwise orthongality is the necessary condition for a list of linear independent vectors, and my question is why is $R^1$ and $R^2$ the exception

Comment: @user2654176: no, it is not.

Comment: @Michael which part, the whole part?

Comment: @user2654176 Orthogonality is not a requirement for linear independence, period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It is not a requirement**

Two vectors must be at right angles for them to be [orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality). Sometime we require that the vectors themselves have unit length, but not always. In vector language, *orthogonal* is often used in the same way as *perpendicular* is with lines, i.e. at right angles.

The vectors $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$ are linearly indepndent in the plane but *they are not orthogonal*. The angle between $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$ is $45^{\circ}$. For orthogonality, we need the angle to be $90^{\circ}$.

Orthogonal vectors in the plane are *always* linearly independent, but the converse is false: there exist non-orthogonal vectors which are linearly independent.